# How to open bookmarks in a new Tab Group on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, browser-tabs

Is there a way to open a site saved into my bookmarks, or even a folder of bookmarks, directly into a new Tab Group on Google Chrome?
Also, if it's possible to do the same into an existing Tab Group would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I think you're asking if you can open a bookmarked site on a new tab group. I believe you can drag and drop them into the group from the bookmark folder. If not that I have no idea. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking that, and yes, I can do that, but a feature like what I said would be awesome. I wonder if there is a Chrome Extension with this functionality...